# BackupAgentHelper with multiple sets of SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, backup, sharedpreferences

I have trouble unterstanding the keyPrefix of the addHelper() method.
Does it need to be unique for each BackupAgentHelper Class Instance or for each SharedPreferencesBackupHelper ?
I want to backup two or more sets of SharedPreferences:

Example:

```
public class PrefsBackupAgent extends BackupAgentHelper {

    // Allocate a helper and add it to the backup agent
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        SharedPreferencesBackupHelper user1 = new SharedPreferencesBackupHelper(this, "user1_preferences");
        addHelper('prefs', user1); // <-- keyPrefix same to both addHelper Calls?

        SharedPreferencesBackupHelper user2 = new SharedPreferencesBackupHelper(this, "user2_preferences");
        addHelper('prefs', user2); // <--
    }
}
```

or does it need to look like that:

```
public class PrefsBackupAgent extends BackupAgentHelper {

    // Allocate a helper and add it to the backup agent
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        SharedPreferencesBackupHelper user1 = new SharedPreferencesBackupHelper(this, "user1_preferences");
        addHelper('user1', user1); // <-- or do they need to be unique for each SharedPreferencesBackupHelper ?

        SharedPreferencesBackupHelper user2 = new SharedPreferencesBackupHelper(this, "user2_preferences");
        addHelper('user2', user2); // <--
    }
}
```

Which one is the correct way?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your first example is correct.

```
public class MyBackupAgentHelper extends BackupAgentHelper {

    static final String DEFAULT_PREFS = "packagename_preferences";
    static final String OTHER_PREFS = "packagename_other_preference";

    // A key to uniquely identify the set of backup data
    static final String PREFS_BACKUP_KEY = "prefs";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        SharedPreferencesBackupHelper helper1 = new SharedPreferencesBackupHelper(this, DEFAULT_PREFS);
        SharedPreferencesBackupHelper helper2 = new SharedPreferencesBackupHelper(this, OTHER_PREFS);
        addHelper(PREFS_BACKUP_KEY, helper1);
        addHelper(PREFS_BACKUP_KEY, helper2);
    }
}
```